# Console & Logging In Node.js From A HTTP interface

Tags: node.js, console

I have a difficult question that needs some answering, i have seen some projects where 
the application runs a socket in a browser that has a console like format that the user can run for their node.js module...

If the actually calling a function or script is impossible from the web side,
i think it would be nifty to just see the console logs in the window.

If any advice could be shared, that would be amazing!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are several projects that do this.  [Weinre](http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre/docs/latest/) is very commonly used.  You can look at its source code to see how it does it.

If I were to build it from scratch, I would utilize [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).  Send the command, return the result.

Comment: I have fumbled around with socket.IO for a while, but i just dont understand it ALL... do you know of any tutorials possibly?

Comment: Iv seen some minecraft integration, and some other video on chatting, but im still scratching my head on how i use this module system?

Comment: @ChristopherKemp, The best tutorial is simply to do the example on their homepage.  What don't you understand about it?  You emit an event on one side, and it is fired on the other.  In your case, you would do something like `socket.emit('command', 'console.log(\'something\')')`.  On the server... `socket.on('command', function (command) { eval(command); })`.  (Obviously, you will need to send the result back, but this will get you started.)